# Fundamental principle about data transfer on the internet

Tags: networking

Let's assume I open my PC browser in a LAN at my home and type http://foo.com, the browser or another running service find the foo's IP address and send it through ISP to the foo's server.
Now the server knows I sent a request and generate a HTML page or something to respond my request. How its respond arrives to browser in a LAN?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  The request contains the sender's IP address, so the server knows where to send the response to.  Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: You should try to send some requests over the net, and look at it using Fiddler. This will show what is going on under the hood. Though it can look a bit scary if you do not know anything about HTTP headers and so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IP packets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header) contain the IP address of the source (i.e. the sender).  So the server knows who initiated the request, and can then send its response to that IP address (no DNS lookup involved).

One common complexity is in a LAN behind a router using [NAT (network address translation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT); this is the case in most residential settings.  Although all the clients in the LAN have different local IP addresses, the router modifies all the IP packets so that they all have the same IP address (the router's external address).  Therefore all the response traffic all gets sent back to that single IP address.  The router is able to distinguish and send the packets back to the correct local client based on TCP/UDP port number.

Comment: How the requests pass through the LAN?

Answer (score 1):

Browser opens connection to the server and sends the request; server responds through the same connection.

Comment: Only at the TCP level.  What about lower down the stack?

Comment: Client opens a TCP connection between the client's IP and arbitrary port - and server's IP and specific port (usually 80 or 443). Using this connection, client sends data packet(s) (that contains contents of the higer protocol, HTTP) to the server and this connection between these to ports remains opened - and server reuses this connection for the response. If the higher protocol is HTTP 1.0, the connection is closed after the reply, if it's 1.1, it remains opened for other requests, until client or server close it.

Comment: @Robert: What the OP is interested in is how the response data gets back to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Its nicely explained at:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780783(WS.10).aspx